# What is the best way to find an alternative monospace font for a non-monospace font that has the same look and feel?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-recommendation, typesetting, monospace

Just wondering if anyone has come across the same issue of having to replace a non-monospaced font with one that is monospaced while retaining a similar look & feel (or if this is even possible/recommended).

I assume that there are tools that will match fonts for you based on particular characteristics, but I normally like to overlay one font over another and see where the differences are to get a better feel for this.

However, I think this would be easier if both fonts are monospaced or not monospaced, so I am wondering if there are any tips or suggestions for those who have had to do this in the past.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually complex families that include both regular and mono weights, but one that I've personally used is the [TT Interphases](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/type-type/tt-interfaces/) family. Other options are Almarena/Mono and Decima/Mono. Probably other good ones with a bit of research.

With one of these, you are certain to use *"the same look & feel"*, as they're made by the same designer as part of the same typeface design.

[image]

Comment: For half a second, I thought someone had come up with a monospacedcompanion to [Inter](https://rsms.me/inter/)!

Comment: I agree that finding fonts in the same family is the best way to go, but I'm not sure that the example you provided is a good one.  Comparing the I and the r between  Mono and the other examples, we see those strong horizontals that make it look pretty different.  FF Attribute Mono and Text seem more closely visually related (after a random search which showed that the "problem" was more wide-spread than I assumed)

Comment: I was just illustrating my point about the families with mono's included, not doing someone's homework :)

Answer (score 1):

Christopher Bergman's Isoglosse blog has an [interesting list of "not quite monospaced" fonts](https://www.isoglosse.de/2018/02/proportionally-spaced-typefaces-with-a-monospaced-appearance/).

Comment: I think this is solving the opposite problem: a font that looks like a monospace one but not being monospace, whereas the OP asks for a monospace font that looks like a given proportional one as far as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but you could identify similar fonts to yours using [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

It's a simple upload and will suggest a long list of fonts with similar characteristics. If the list doesn't have the spacing you want, you could look further into the font families

[image]

You could then take these screenshots with your custom text to Photoshop and use layers set with transparency or different blending modes to find your closest match